# Swift: Unknown Error While Attempting to Play an Audio File

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am currently developing an app using SpriteKit in Xcode (ver 9.4). Before a couple of hours ago, I was having no problems or bugs in my code and everything was working perfectly. I made some minor code changes but nothing too drastic. At some point in the past hour, a majority of my audio files stopped playing.

Some code where bulletSound and backingAudioMain are created as well as functions that use them.

```
let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("bulletSound.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

var backingAudioMain = AVAudioPlayer()

//A function that uses bulletSound
func fireBullet() {
let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bullet")
bullet.name = "Bullet" //Bullet is a reference name for the object bullet
bullet.setScale(1.1)
bullet.position = player.position
bullet.zPosition = 1
bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bullet.size)
bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.Bullet
bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.None
bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.EnemyFighter //we will be told when a bullet hits the enemy
self.addChild(bullet)

let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 0.8) //Bullet moves to the top of the scene height plus the height of the bullet so it goes just off screen
let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent() //once the bullet is just off screen, the bullet is deleted to preserve memory
let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet]) //Sequences off the two actions above
bullet.run(bulletSequence)}

//A function that uses backingAudioMain
func playMusic(){
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"backingAudioMain", ofType: "wav")
let audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)

do{ backingAudioMain = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL)}
catch { return print ("Cannot find the audio.")}

backingAudioMain.numberOfLoops = -1
backingAudioMain.play()}
```

Here are some errors from the debugger when attempting to use the fireBullet function.

```
2018-09-27 10:34:16.414492-0400 Solo Mission[8410:191101] [aqme] 202: err 1718449215
2018-09-27 10:34:16.426109-0400 Solo Mission[8410:191101] [aqme] 202: err 1718449215
2018-09-27 10:34:19.127161-0400 Solo Mission[8410:190608] AUBase.cpp:832:DispatchSetProperty:  ca_require: ValidFormat(inScope, inElement, newDesc) InvalidFormat
2018-09-27 10:34:19.129167-0400 Solo Mission[8410:190608] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "bulletSound.wav"
2018-09-27 10:34:19.151046-0400 Solo Mission[8410:191101] [aqme] 202: err 1718449215
2018-09-27 10:34:21.597514-0400 Solo Mission[8410:190608] SKAction: Error loading sound resource: "bulletSound.wav"
```

I have noticed that only my backingAudioMain file, which is an AVAudioPlayer, is playing. After several hours of trying to fix and research the problem, I have come up with nothing. I am thinking this is a problem on Xcode's end but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent() //once the bullet is just off screen, the bullet is deleted to preserve memory
let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet]) //Sequences off the two actions above
bullet.run(bulletSequence)
```

So the sound action never has a chance to play, because the delete action interrupts it. To see this, change the second line to

```
let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet])
```

If you are going to remove from parent, insert a `wait` action into the sequence, e.g. `SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Only issue is, I've had that line of code since the beginning of my project, and never any issues. Only recently did I start having issues with it. Also, I have waitForCompletion = false, so shouldn't that work fine?

Comment: My answer includes a test that will show whether or not it is on the right track. Did you try doing what I suggested? Sure, if that doesn't help, then the answer is not useful, but you can't find out without trying it.

Comment: Also, as I said in an earlier comment, if you know you recently introduced a change that caused the problem, it's easy to roll back to your earlier git commit and find out what the change was.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try everything you recommended and let you know if anything ends up working :) thanks!